# Making the use of a dropdown compulsory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make using a dropdown compulsory. This is my code:

```
<form class=​"add-to-cart clearfix" action=​"http:​/​/​www.MyWebsite.com/​cart/​add/​38561016/​" id=​"product_configure_form" method=​"post">
    <input type=​"hidden" name=​"bundle_id" id=​"product_configure_bundle_id" value>
    <div class=​"product-configure">
        <div class=​"product-configure-variants">​
            <label for=​"product_configure_variants">​"Make a choice: "<em>​*​</em>​</label>
            <select name=​"variant" id=​"product_configure_variants" onchange=​"document.getElementById('product_configure_form')​.action = 'http:​/​/​www.photographycoursetour.com/​product/​variants/​20882492/​';​ document.getElementById('product_configure_form')​.submit()​;​" >
                <option value=​"38561016" selected=​"selected">​PLEASE SELECT - €5.995,00​</option>
                <option value=​"37213514">​2 APR - 16 APR 16 - €5.995,00​</option>
                <option value=​"37213516">​5 NOV - 19 JAN 16 - €4.499,00​</option>
            </select>
            <div class=​"product-configure-clear">​</div>
        ​</div>
        <a href=​"javascript:​;​" onclick=​"$('#product_configure_form')​.submit()​;​" title=​"Add to cart" class=​"btn large">​Add to cart​</a>​
    </div>
</form>
```

If there is no way to make the use of the dropdown compulsory, then maybe an alert is possible?

I tried this (but it did not work):

```
<script>
if ($_POST[‘variant'] == '38561016')
{
    $errors[] = 'Please select a tour date';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest way to do this is to give it attribute `required`:

```
<select .... required>
```

But if you wanna be more cautious and use jQuery then you need to let jQuery run *on submit*  to verify if it has been selected. So first of all, modify the `<from>`:

```
<form .... onsubmit=foo()>
```

And then use your jQuery code. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Problem is the dropdown code is generated by a backoffice. Therefore I need a script that will work on that generated code.

Comment: use the script below. in the scope of the `product_configure_variants` you can get the value of the current option with `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 0):

also you should use a button instead of a link to submit the form. a button in a form has the default `type="submit"` to submit the form.

```
<button title="Add to cart" class="btn large">
```

do not use inline JS when you use jQuery.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $('#product_configure_variants').on('change', function() {
            // submit form here with another action
        });
    });
</script>
```

alert a message:

```
<script>
    var showError = <?php echo $_POST['variant'] == '38561016' ?> == 1;
    if(showError) {
        alert('Please select a tour date');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code is generated by a backoffice which I cannot change. Is there no way to achieve this by using a script that acts on the existing code?